# set data range automatically by skipping n rows when new data is added

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have multiple graphs in an excel. I would like to automatically set the data range when new data is added and refresh button is hit.

One example:

If there is a line graph with X -axis as date and Y-axis as Time spent, and the data range is currently ='All RawData'!$A$1368:$A$1372,'All RawData'!$D$1368:$D$1372.

Output:

Next time, when the data is added and the refresh data button is hit, I want the data range to be automatically set by selecting 5 rows after skipping 10 rows from the above current range.
='All RawData'!$A$1382:$A$1386,'All RawData'!$D$1382:$D$1386.

Any solution for this would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is _selecting 5 rows after skipping 10 rows_ the same as selecting the last four rows in the data table?  The two examples you give are four rows each, so wondering if it's just taking the last four rows?  If so you can put your data in an Excel table and use the formula `=TAKE(Table1[Date],-4)` to grab the last four rows.  Then have your charts reference those formula.